# Работа скриптов в фоновом режиме

Tags: javascript, html, браузер

Скрипт останавливается, когда перехожу на другую вкладку. Есть какая-нибудь функция в браузере, чтобы это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте копнуть в сторону web worker'ов: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: Насколько я помню отключить это не получится последних пять..может шесть версий стали останавливать скрипты  в целях енергоэффективности .. ну и так далее по. но это неточно...